# Should I select Statics cells or Dynamic Prototype

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

hello I want to implement a table like this

[image]

first,I don't know what this table is using.

should I use `static cells` and `sections` or should I use `dynamic Prototype` with the style `Grouped`?

I am confused as I am new and don't know much difference in static cell and dynamic cell.

I want to ask How can I set left and right margins around `tableView` like this image?

Comment: you can use custom tableview cell

Comment: @DivyeshSavaliya where is this option ?

Comment: look at this tutorial - http://www.raywenderlich.com/87975/dynamic-table-view-cell-height-ios-8-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then you can Use Dynamic table View setting with custom TableView Cells. The process to setting  the Custom Cells. you can follow the steps from here .
http://www.appcoda.com/customize-table-view-cells-for-uitableview/